# Local notifications not working for some users (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, notifications, ios8

I have an app which uses local notifications and ti used to work fine in previous versions. I have updated the app for iOS 8 and tested and worked fine. After submitting the update to app store, a small number of users are complaining that they don't get any local notifications. However, a larger number of users that I've checked are fine and don't observe any issues.

For the users with the error (at least one of them), they can not see the "Notifications" item in the "Settings->myApp" screen; The whole option is missing not that it is disabled. "Location" and "Use Cellular Data" are in that screen but not the Notifications. I have tried to change the settings under "Settings->Notifications->myApp" and it work as expected.

Any suggestions for how to debug this issue would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180806/app-with-local-notifications-not-appearing-in-notification-center-list-in-settin?rq=1

Comment: Same issue (another): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827650/app-from-app-store-doesnt-show-up-for-all-users-under-notification-center-loca?rq=1

Comment: I have the same issue. Glad to see I'm not alone. I hope someone finds an answer soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this for Objective-C:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// are you running on iOS8?
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) 
  {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  } 
else // iOS 7 or earlier
  {
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
  }
}
```

For Swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
 if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")))
 {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))
 }
 else
 {
    //
 }
return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I select this as the correct answer as this was the first one to answer. Before these answers are posted, I've implemented this same code (registerUserNotificationSettings) and asked one of my users to test using Ad-hoc testing and he confirmed that the issue is resolved. **In iOS 8, local notifications are also required to be registered**.

Answer (score 1):

First You have to Register to Use Local Push Notification

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

then you can send Local Push Notification By This

```
 UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
notification.alertBody = @"Local Push !!!";
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void EnableLocalNotificationIOS8
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    if ([app respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [app registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [app registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
}
```